# Unable to add text to InlineCssTextArea in RichTextFX

Tags: java, javafx, richtextfx

I am new to use the RichTextFX for my JAVAFX project. But I find that I cannot add the text to the InlineCssTextArea. In the project I used the MVC design and generate the UI code from the Scene Builder. The InlineCssTextArea is succesfully created but I cannot figure out why I cannot add text content.The program successfully compiled without error.But the InlineCssTextArea is empty as default.

I have read the official demos of the RichTextFX on Github, but they build up the UI purely from code but not from Scene Builder.

The release "fat" version of the library required :https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX

Thank you

> Tree structure

```
> ├───library
> │       richtextfx-fat-0.10.2.jar
> │
> │
> └───src
>         Main.fxml
>         Main.java
>         specialController.java
```

> Main.fxml:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea?>

<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="specialController">
  <children>
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-1.0" maxWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <InlineCssTextArea fx:id="specialArea" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="346.0" prefWidth="611.0" />
         </children>
    </AnchorPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

> Main.java

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    private static final String indexFXMLFileName="Main.fxml";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent index= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(indexFXMLFileName));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Writing Assitant Index");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(index));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> specialController.java

```java
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea;

public class specialController{
    @FXML
    public InlineCssTextArea specialArea;

    public specialController() {
        String alphabet = "Remember when you were a careless eight year old kid riding a bike with your friends, racing each other around the neighborhood? ";
        specialArea = new InlineCssTextArea(alphabet);
    }
}
```

Comment: you _must not_ instantiate fields that are injected by fxml. Doing so will configure the field that you create in the constructor which is overwritten later by another instance injected by fxml. And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: But If I need to change the value of the InlineCssTextArea, is there any approach to that?

Comment: I remember others like combo box can be changed after injection of fxml. I dont know why this one cannot be done?

Comment: do it in initialize .. and remove the manual instantiation ... it's __plain wrong__

Comment: I finally found the solution. Thank you.

Comment: cool :) now fix the violation of naming conventions (classes start with a capital letter) and consider posting the solution as an answer (then it's easier to find for future readers)

Comment: I will fix it now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Change the `specialController.java` to this. Thanks to @kleopatra. Except the problem for re-instantiation mentioned by kleopatra, the major problem was that I didn't realize the difference between `initialize` and `constructor`, and therefore I tried to manipulate before the initialization of the controls, which caused the nullPointerException. There are already some answers related the difference between these two on StackOverflow.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class specialController implements Initializable {

    public InlineCssTextArea specialArea;

    public specialController() {
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        String alphabet = "Remember when you were a careless eight year old kid riding a bike with your friends, racing each other around the neighborhood? ";
        specialArea.deleteText(0,specialArea.getLength());
        specialArea.appendText(alphabet);
        specialArea.setPrefWidth(400);
        specialArea.setPrefHeight(600);
    }
}
```